# Cannot assign to read only property: Typescript + Babel

Tags: typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm having an issue during runtime with my compiled typescript. My chain is Typescript -> es6 modules -> webpack + babelify.

The file in question is

```
import Registry from "../registry";

class Alert {

    public static name = "alert";

    public static options = {
        template: require("./alert.mustache")
    };
}

Registry.register(Alert);
```

This gets compiled via es2015 plugin + webpack to

```
"use strict";

var _registry = __webpack_require__(14);

var _registry2 = _interopRequireDefault(_registry);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

var Alert = function Alert() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Alert);
};

Alert.name = "alert";
Alert.options = {
    template: __webpack_require__(16)
};
_registry2.default.register(Alert);
//# sourceMappingURL=alert.js.map

/*****************
 ** WEBPACK FOOTER
 ** alert.js
 ** module id = 15
 ** module chunks = 0
 **/
```

but when executed, gets this error:

```
alert.js:15 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function Alert() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Alert);
}
```

I've tried a bunch of different methods, but I don't see why having static properties on a class would cause this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a typescript compiler problem: in ES2015 the `name` function property is read only. So a TS compiler must take that into account.

Comment: Wow thank you so much. You just saved me a ton of trouble.

Comment: If you file a bug could you please provide a link?

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/442

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` property is a [reserved property on functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) that describes the name of the function, i.e. for `function foo()`, `foo.name === 'foo'`. It is defined in the EcmaScript specification as being a read-only property. So your transpiled code ends up trying to assign to the `name` property of your `Alert` function, which is read-only, and this fails:

```
var Alert = function Alert() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Alert);
};

// This is not allowed, because
// [[Function]].name is a read-only property.
Alert.name = "alert";
```

Comment: "it is transpiled down to" --- if the compiler used the `Map` to keep the static members it would not be a problem though.

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand your comment. Why does it matter hypothetically what a compiler might be able to do to avoid a name collision? The compiler could obfuscate the name of the property for runtime too to avoid the collision. So can you explain what you mean by this?

Comment: It's an addition to your answer: that the compiler does not have to do that straight 1:1 translation of identifier names in TS to identifiers in JS. And to emphasize that usually it's the compiler responsibility to mangle names, not the user's problems to take into account some limitation of the underlying runtime (which you don't even have a direct access to).

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
class Alert {

    public static name = "alert";
```

is **invalid** at runtime. You cannot write the `name` property of a *function* (which is what a class is if you transpile to es5). Use the `instanceof` operator for class instance checks.

[There is an open issue on github to turn this into a compiler error](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/442).

Comment: "is invalid at runtime" --- what does this exactly mean? Is it invalid as per the TS language standard?

Comment: No as per JavaScript standard. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name : `Writable : no`

Comment: And that's incorrect: the high level language must address the low level language nuances. Stating that it is "invalid" just because the compiler has a bug is wrong.

Comment: Compiler has a bug. Its invalid at runtime. I don't see us disagreeing

Comment: "The code is invalid at runtime" --- is fundamentally wrong. Code can be syntactically wrong or its runtime semantics might be wrong if only the language standard/specification says so. Does the TS specification forbids a user from using a static member with name `name`? "You cannot write the name property of a function" --- the code does not modify the `name` property of the function. The code defines a static member of a class.

Comment: In the latest node v20, this code is legal and works. I've also run it in Chromium 116.0.5845.110 and it also works.

I think perhaps with native classes, this is no longer a problem. However `tsc` chokes on compiling the code.